# How to get the key from a JSON to display into a textarea

Tags: javascript, html

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JSON Parser</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>This is a JSON parser example:</h2>
        <!--data to be parsed: { "Device":"Computer", "Quantity":30, "Specification":"Class A"} -->
        <p id="JSON:">{ "Device":"Computer", "Quantity":30, "Specification":"Class A"}</p>
        <label>Converted to XML</label><br>
        <textarea disabled rows="10" cols="60" id="display"></textarea><br>
        <button onclick="jParse()">Click me to Parse</button>
        <button onclick="toXML()">Click me to Convert</button>
        <script>
            var txt = '{ "Device":"Computer", "Quantity":30, "Specification":"Class A"}';
            //var txt = { "Device":"Computer"};
            var obj = JSON.parse(txt);

            function jParse(){
                alert("Device: " + obj.Device + 
                "\nQuantity: "+ obj.Quantity + 
                "\nSpecification: "+ obj.Specification);
            }
            function toXML(){
                var txt2 = {"Device":"Computer", "Quantity":30, "Specification":"Class A"};

                var keys = Object.keys(txt2);
                alert("yes");
                var xmlText = console.log(keys[0])
                document.getElementById("display").value=xmlText
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

So basically what I'm trying to do here is to get `device` into the text area as an output. This sort of works but it outputs `undefined` instead. This code looks messy because I've been trying all sorts of ways to try and make it at least display something, I'm a complete noob in web programming (literally started like a few hours ago).

Comment: Do you just want to set `document.getElementById("display").value=keys[0]`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are trying to display "Computer" in the textArea (key[0] is "Device"), then to access the value in your Object you could do txt[keys[0]], so you can access the value "Device" of the txt Object.
Also, you have stored a console.log() inside a function, you don't get any value from that variable when you try to access it later just store it like this.

```
xmlText = txt[keys[0]]
```

then

```
console.log(xmlText)
```

if you want to console log it

if you then do

```
document.getElementById("display").value = xmlText
```

the value "Computer" will appear in the textbox

Comment: Thank you, I was just getting very confused. I couldn't find any other solution that outputted the Object other than to console.log, so I assumed that I could maybe just grab that value from the log and use it.

Answer (score 2):

This is happening because you're outputting the result of a call to `console.log()`, which returns undefined (its job is to write something to the console, not return a value).

You simply need:

```
document.getElementById("display").value= keys[0];
```

Note also `var` is deprecated and you should use `let` or `const` these days. Also beaware non-indicative variable/function naming. Your `jParse()` function, for example, doesn't do any parsing. And your `xmlText` variable doesn't have anything to do with XML.

Answer (score 1):

If you are trying to set the value of a key to an element then,
on the line that reads `var xmlText = console.log(keys[0])` change it to,

`var xmlText = text2[keys[0]]`

Answer (score 0):

here you go :

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>JSON Parser</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h2>This is a JSON parser example:</h2>
        <!--data to be parsed: { "Device":"Computer", "Quantity":30, "Specification":"Class A"} -->
        <p id="JSON:">{ "Device":"Computer", "Quantity":30, "Specification":"Class A"}</p>
        <label>Converted to XML</label><br>
        <textarea disabled rows="10" cols="60" id="display"></textarea><br>
        <button onclick="jParse()">Click me to Parse</button>
        <button onclick="toXML()">Click me to Convert</button>
        <script>
            var txt = '{ "Device":"Computer", "Quantity":30, "Specification":"Class A"}';
            //var txt = { "Device":"Computer"};
            var obj = JSON.parse(txt);

           
           
            

            function jParse(){
                alert("Device: " + obj.Device + 
                "\nQuantity: "+ obj.Quantity + 
                "\nSpecification: "+ obj.Specification);
            }
            function toXML(){
                var txt2 = {"Device":"Computer", "Quantity":30, "Specification":"Class A"};

                var keys = Object.keys(txt2);
                alert(keys);
                var xmlText = keys;
                document.getElementById("display").value=xmlText
            }


        </script>
    
    
    
    </body>


</html>
```

Issue is `console.log(keys[0])` is for print into browser console. so you need to perform assignment operation here like

```
var xmlText = keys;
```